# Why does PackageReference list longer than usual Nuget package manager?

Tags: c#, nuget, packagereference

Every time I upload a new version of my package I have to wait for it for a quite long time. I know that it has to be prepared and checked there somehow but when I receive an email from *Nuget.org* - I am able to download the package by *right-clicking on my project -> Manage Nuget packages...* but not via `<PackageReference/>`. After the email I have to wait for about 15 minutes before it gets listed by `<PackageReference/>`. What could be the reason of this? Is there a way to speed it up?

p.s. I found out that it gets listed only when I *right-click on my project -> Manage Nuget packages...* and do some useless things there like opening/closing combobox of versions, searching for the package and clicking everywhere (where nothing special should happen)

p.s.2 I also found out that you should not instantly change the *PackageReference* to a new version of package but should wait for some time (about 5 minutes) and then it would work fine. Probably there is a problem with VS package manager